# Contact form not redirecting correctly at submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got a contact form that you reach by pressing the phone and then contact form on the screen. Feel free to test mail me through it, no problem. When I press submit I get redirected to submit and the contact form is gone as well.

I'm trying to achieve something along the lines of redirecting to http://developed-web.com/404.php for now, just to confirm a working redirect. Where do I decide this?

The code

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        $formproc->_redirect("http://developed-web.com/404.php");
   }
}
```

doesn't seem to do anything.

**EDIT:**

I'm also including a file that contains

```
function RedirectToURL($url)
{
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```

Is it relevant?

Comment: Are using any framework that we should be aware of?

Comment: Not that I know of. I got this form from http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/creating-a-contact-form.html but modified it to work without an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to redirect a page if the headers have already been passed. 
In order to redirect use

`ob_start()` at the beginning of the code to "withhold" the headers

and then `ob_end_flush()` at the end of the code to send the headers, and then you will be able to redirect the page.

Comment: At the beginning of your php file put `ob_start();`, and at the end of your php file put `ob_end_flush();`

You can read more about output buffering here:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: Output buffering shouldn't be the solution here. The OP should simply not output anything before making a redirect. Like MVC for instance. If you use the MVC pattern, you won't have this problem.